# get checkbox state inside GridView with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have GridView with more Checkbox and i need know what is the checkBox state. As stated at the end of the post i received error when i insert RelativeLayout, ImageView and TextView in my XML.

i received this log:

```
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443): Process:       com.kirolm.instalacionesdep, PID: 3443
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):     java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.search.BuscarInstalacionesActividadFragment.ge    tItemCheked(BuscarInstalacionesActividadFragment.java:218)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.search.BuscarInstalacionesActividadFragment.on    OptionsItemSelected(BuscarInstalacionesActividadFragment.java:123)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1806)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1972)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2603)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1065)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
 05-05 22:03:29.375: E/AndroidRuntime(3443):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_fragment_imageview_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/header_buscar_actividad" />

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_fragment_tv_titulo_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                      android:text="@string/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_fragment_titulo_header"
                      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_fragment_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" >
    </GridView>
```

and this is my getItemChecked() method:

```
    public ArrayList<String> getItemCheked(){
    ArrayList<String> checkResultArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    int count = grid.getAdapter().getCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)grid.getChildAt(i);
        CheckBox chb = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_item_chb);
        if(chb.isChecked()){
            String valor = (String) chb.getTag();
            checkResultArray.add(valor);
            Log.e("Checking", "BuscarInstalacionesActividadActivity: El boton pulsado es: "+valor );
        }
    }
    return checkResultArray;
}
```

The line 218 is this:

```
CheckBox chb = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_item_chb);
```

If i delete this in my xml, it runs ok, but i need that RelativeLayout, ImageView and textView.

```
        <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_fragment_imageview_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/header_buscar_actividad" />

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_fragment_tv_titulo_header"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                      android:text="@string/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_fragment_titulo_header"
                      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**
I forgot, I inflate checkboxes inside custom adapter.

This is getView method in my Adapter.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View grid;

    if (convertView == null) {   
    grid = new View(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_check_item, null);               



    }  else {
        grid = (View) convertView;

    }        
    tv = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_item_text);
    tv.setText(items.get(position).getNombreActividad());
    chb = (CheckBox) grid.findViewById(R.id.buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_item_chb);

    chb.setTag(items.get(position).getTipoActividad());

    String fotoActividad = items.get(position).getFotoActividad();
    fotoActividad = "checkbox_"+fotoActividad;
    int imagenParaMostrar = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fotoActividad, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    if(imagenParaMostrar == 0){

        fotoActividad = "checkbox_actividad_sinfoto";
        imagenParaMostrar = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fotoActividad, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        Log.e("Checking", "CheckableImageGridActividadesAdapter. El nombre de la imagen es: "+fotoActividad);

    }
    chb.setButtonDrawable(imagenParaMostrar);


    tv.setSelected(false);
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setSelected(true);
        }
    };
    tv.setOnClickListener(handler);

    return grid; 
    }
```

And this is buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_check_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/album_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/white"
android:padding="10dp">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_item_chb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_actividad_activity_grid_item_chb"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="detalles"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't see your checkbox in your layout, is it normal?

Comment: Sorry, i edited my post and write more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use grid.getAdapter().getCount() I believe what you want is grid.getAdapter().getItem(i) instead of grid.getChildAt(i). And since grid.getChildAt(i) seems to return null that should be the reason for your problem.

So just replace :

```
RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)grid.getChildAt(i);
```

By :

```
RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)grid.getAdapter().getItem(i);
```

Edit:

Sorry, I was wrong, forgot getItem doesn't return the view but the object corresponding to it. But maybe you could set an OnCheckedChangeListener on checkboxes that update a boolean in your item 'Actividad' and simply get the boolean this way :

```
boolean b = ((Actividad)grid.getAdapter().getItem(i)).getterForTheBoolean();
```

In getView:

```
chb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
//....
items.get(position).setterForTheBoolean(isChecked);

});
```

Comment: Ok so my answer should work fine. use Adapter.getItem instead of getChildAt.
Just note that you set grid = new View(context); and just below reset grid with another value without ever using your new View so I'm not sure if it is usefull, but it is not what causes your problem.

Comment: Now I get this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.model.Actividad cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout`

Comment: Sorry. I have not understood. You tell me that I implements OnCheckedChangeListener in my Adapter?